# Why are two exceptions thrown when using subprocess.run()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python subprocess.run() to process some command. I want to capture output/error/return code, and want to have timeout if the command is blocked.
The code is simple:

```
cmd = "ping 1.1.1.1 -n 5"
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, timeout=2)
```

But the result confuses me, why are two exception thrown?

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = "ping 1.1.1.1 -n 5"
>>> subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, timeout=2)
PING 5 (0.0.0.5) 56(124) bytes of data.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 425, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 863, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1560, in _communicate
    self.wait(timeout=self._remaining_time(endtime))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1469, in wait
    raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, timeout)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command 'ping 1.1.1.1 -n 5' timed out after 1.999514610040933 seconds

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 430, in run
    stderr=stderr)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command 'ping 1.1.1.1 -n 5' timed out after 2 seconds
>>>
```

Comment: waist some time to paste code and trace.

Comment: The first exception rose from your command reaching the timeout value you specified - 2s. The second exception occurred while handling the first exception.

Comment: Are you running this inside a larger script, or from an interactive interpreter session?

Comment: @jhelphenstine, just reproduced it from python intepreter. and modified my post

Comment: Thanks, I've reproduced it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not handling the exception of subprocess.run(). The [Python documentation for subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) contains a similar example, and it also shows a traceback:

```
>>> subprocess.run("exit 1", shell=True, check=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'exit 1' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Because you're not handling the exception, python is giving you tracebacks as it fails out. Since you're intentionally looking for exceptions (TimeoutExpired), you'll need to handle it. Here's an example for your command:

```
import sys
import subprocess

f = open('output.txt', 'w') # store stdout
g = open('error.txt', 'w') # store stderr

cmd = "ping 8.8.8.8 -n -c 5"

try:
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=False, stdout=f, stderr=g timeout=2)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as t:
    print("Timeout expired!")
    print(t.timeout)
```

The output from this is:

```
Timeout expired!
2
```

The 2 is the timeout threshold -- [subprocess.TimeoutExpired](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=timeoutexpired#subprocess.TimeoutExpired) has other attributes you could print::

```
cmd
    Command that was used to spawn the child process.
timeout
    Timeout in seconds.
output
    Output of the child process if it was captured by run() or check_output(). Otherwise, None.
stdout
    Alias for output, for symmetry with stderr.
stderr
    Stderr output of the child process if it was captured by run(). Otherwise, None.
```

I created output.txt and error.txt in my local directory to catch stdout and stderr, which answers the other part of your ask, how to record the command's output and error as well as the timeout.

Comment: sure I will handle it in later code, but the problem is, it suppose to throw one exception, right? In most cases, when several exception thrown, it is a design issue, at least the code is messy.

Comment: The example I've provided doesn't throw tracebacks. Because it's using the except, it correctly catches the TimeoutExpired error. I chose to print it in the except block, but if you wanted to save it for later, you could adjust my `except TimeoutError` block to simply store the attributes you're interested in.

Comment: you code is good, I am just not happy about the subprocess lib, but maybe it is common to throw exception in exception in Python.

Comment: @cso I updated it to meet your other requirement wrt storing output & stderr, as well; you could also consider using the stdout and stderr attributes within the exception, too.

Comment: Thanks, @jhelphenstine. A nit: suggest printing a more complete and clear error report using just 't' instead of 't.timeout' as with 'print(t, file=sys.stderr)'

Answer (score 0):

if you want a certain number of pings, then the option is 'c'. if you want a timeout to the ping command, the option is 'w'.

```
>>> subprocess.run("ping -w 3 127.0.0.1".split())
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.125 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.052/0.092/0.125/0.031 ms
CompletedProcess(args=['ping', '-w', '3', '127.0.0.1'], returncode=0)
```

wrapping in a try/except means that it doesn't matter if there are multiple  exceptions:

```
>>> try:
...   subprocess.run("ping 127.0.0.1".split(), timeout=2)
... except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
...   print('handle')
... 
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.163 ms
handle
```

Comment: what I want is a general solution for any command. If the command takes long time, then it should be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem. But I've caused it myself - on behalf of good IDE advice :-D. I've handled TimeoutExpired properly, but at the end of except block I've risen another exception and used `from`. It has risen TimeoutExpired too which was not handled again.

```
try:
    check_output(...)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as problem:
    # some logging stuff
    raise ConnectionError("Some useful info") from problem
```